# How can I get the current route name with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-routing

I have an application that is written on the top of ASP.NET Core 2.2 framework.

I have the following controller

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [Route("some-parameter-3/{name}/{id:int}/{page:int?}", Name = "SomeRoute3Name")]
    [Route("some-parameter-2/{name}/{id:int}/{page:int?}", Name = "SomeRoute2Name")]
    [Route("some-parameter-1/{name}/{id:int}/{page:int?}", Name = "SomeRoute1Name")]
    public ActionResult Act(ActVM viewModel)
    {
        // switch the logic based on the route name

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

How can I get the route name in the action and/or the view?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside of a controller, you can read the [`AttributeRouteInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.attributerouteinfo) from the [`ControllerContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllercontext)'s [`ActionDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor). `AttributeRouteInfo` has a [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.attributerouteinfo.name#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Routing_AttributeRouteInfo_Name) property, which holds the value you're looking for:

```
public ActionResult Act(ActVM viewModel)
{
    switch (ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Name)
    {
        // ...
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Inside of a Razor view, the `ActionDescriptor` is available via the [`ViewContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.viewcontext) property:

```
@{
    var routeName = ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

For me the answer by @krik-larkin didn't work as `AttributeRouteInfo` was always null in my case.

I used the following code instead:

```cs
var endpoint = HttpContext.GetEndpoint() as RouteEndpoint;
var routeNameMetadata = endpoint?.Metadata.OfType<RouteNameMetadata>().SingleOrDefault();
var routeName = routeNameMetadata?.RouteName;
```

Comment: Exactly same in my situation. This should be marked as answer. Thank you

Comment: Works like a champ in .NET 8

Answer (score 2):

Small correction to Kirk Larkin answer. Sometimes you have to use Template property instead of Name:

```
var ari = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo;
var route = ari.Name ?? ari.Template;
```

Answer (score 2):

For .NET 6:

Accepted answer not working for me neither.

This worked however:

```
var routeName = (HttpContext.GetEndpoint() as RouteEndpoint).RoutePattern.RawText;
```