# How to do conditional routing in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, attributerouting

I'd like to create routings like below

```
[HttpPost("device/{id}/disable")]
[HttpPost("device/{id}/enable")]
public async Task SetDevice(stirng id, bool state)
```

And when the user hit the "device/{id}/disable", the state var will automatically assigned with false, and vise versa. How can I achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options or maybe more:

**Use route names**:

```
[HttpPost("device/{id}/disable", Name = "disable_device")]
[HttpPost("device/{id}/enable", Name = "enable_device")]
public async Task SetDevice(stirng id){
   //...
   //get current route name here and implement your logic
   //...
{
```

If you want to know how to get the route name in your action or razor view see [get current route name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022268/how-can-i-get-the-current-route-name-with-asp-net-core).

**Or use default route values:**

```
[HttpPost("device/{id}/disable/{state=false}")]
[HttpPost("device/{id}/enable/{state=true}")]
public async Task SetDevice(stirng id, bool state){
   //...
{
```

Comment: Hi, @Mohammad Barbast, I tested your solution but [HttpPost("device/{id}/disable/{state?=false}")]   causing   RoutePatternException: The route parameter name 'state?' is invalid. Route parameter names must be non-empty and cannot contain these characters: '{', '}', '/'. The '?' character marks a parameter as optional, and can occur only at the end of the parameter. The '*' character marks a parameter as catch-all, and can occur only at the start of the parameter.