# exclude error razor page from OpenIdConnect authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

I am facing an issue with OpenIdConnect authentication in blazor project. If login failed or any exception occur on startup of application during login process then app redirect control to error.razor page, as user is not authenticated application again try to login from error page as well instead of showing error message (infinite loop start between authentication and error.razor). I want to exclude error page from authentication page. I did a lot of search but no found solution of my problem

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));


            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // Instead of using the default validation (validating against a single issuer value, as we do in
                    // line of business apps), we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                    ValidateIssuer = false


                    // If the app is meant to be accessed by entire organizations, add your issuer validation logic here.
                    //IssuerValidator = (issuer, securityToken, validationParameters) => {
                    //    if (myIssuerValidationLogic(issuer)) return issuer;
                    //}
                };

                options.Events = ConfigureOpenIdConnectEvents(services);
            });
        }
```

```
private OpenIdConnectEvents ConfigureOpenIdConnectEvents(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            return new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnTicketReceived = context => Task.CompletedTask,
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    if (CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment()) return Task.CompletedTask;

                    context.Response.Redirect("/Error");

                    context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                // If your application needs to authenticate single users, add your user validation below.
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var client = Client;
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("ClientId", client.Id.ToString()),
                    };
                    var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                    context.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        }
```

Error.Razor page

```
@page "/error"
<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
<h3>Development Mode</h3>
<p>
    Swapping to <strong>Development</strong> environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
</p>
<p>
    <strong>The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.</strong>
    It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users.
    For local debugging, enable the <strong>Development</strong> environment by setting the <strong>ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT</strong> environment variable to <strong>Development</strong>
    and restarting the app.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add authorization tags in error page?

Something like:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <H2> error message authorized</H2>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
         <H2> error message not authorized</H2>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

another approach should be to evaluate the page you're coming from.
Something like:

```
var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint() as RouteEndpoint;
var routeNameMetadata = endpoint?.Metadata.OfType<RouteNameMetadata>().SingleOrDefault();
var routeName = routeNameMetadata?.RouteName;

if (routeName.StartsWith("error")) return Task.CompletedTask;
```

I haven't tried it.
The original solution is from this answer:
[How can I get the current route name with ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022268/how-can-i-get-the-current-route-name-with-asp-net-core)

### Solution 2

From .net 5 we have the possibility to use a new implementation of the `IAllowAnonymous` interface.

Try to add:

```
@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AllowAnonymous]
```

Comment: Hi @Nicola, thanks for reply. Yes i tired above code you have mentioned but still its redirecting for login

Comment: Have you added an @authorize to your import? So every page goes automatically under authorization?

Comment: no. can you please guide how to add. thanks

Comment: If you add `@attribute [Authorize]` to your __Imports.razor__ every page (inside the same project of the __Imports.razor_) will be under _authorize_.

Comment: Currently there is no Authorize attribute on import page. please see attached image
https://i2.paste.pics/5475bab4ab1f66b0ad33ef82ec8bff4e.png

Comment: Have you tried my last solution? I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Nicola. thanks for providing solution but no success. see attached image
https://pasteboard.co/6flRfnOAOaaw.png

Comment: Hi Muhammad, I don't understand. This piece of code is no more needed if you add the @attribute tag.

Comment: Hi tired your both solutions but authentication start loop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035050/5064424 this work for me