# How to exclude a razor page & controller from identify authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, dotnet-httpclient

I've create a blazor web assembly project with identify (individual accounts), and i've created a razor by copying fetchData.razor to a fetchPeople.razor, i want to allow anonymous access for this page, here is my source code

```
@page "/fetchpeople"
@using Booking.Shared
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

@inject HttpClient Http
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

<PageTitle>People</PageTitle>

<h1>People</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Id</td>
                    <td>@forecast.FirstName</td>
                    <td>@forecast.LastName</td>
                    <td>@forecast.LastName</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private PersonModel[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<PersonModel[]>("People");
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using Booking.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Booking.Server.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace a1.Server.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class PeopleController : ControllerBase
    {
     
        private readonly ILogger<PeopleController> _logger;
        private readonly IDataAccess data;


        public PeopleController(ILogger<PeopleController> logger, IDataAccess data)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.data = data;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<PersonModel> Get()
        {
            return data.testSql().Result.ToArray();
        }

    }
}
```

when i access the page , there is an error in console

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: ''
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AccessTokenNotAvailableException: ''
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AuthorizationMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__13`1[[Booking.Shared.PersonModel[], Booking.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at Booking.Client.Pages.FetchPeople.OnInitializedAsync() in E:\2022_hoplun_dotnet\login1\Booking\Booking\Client\Pages\FetchPeople.razor:line 49
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
window.Module.s.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
Fe._internal.dotNetCriticalError @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
St @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
$func219 @ 00971d3e:0x1a492
$func167 @ 00971d3e:0xce60
$func166 @ 00971d3e:0xbd73
$func2815 @ 00971d3e:0xabec4
$func1619 @ 00971d3e:0x6fc85
$func1623 @ 00971d3e:0x702f2
$mono_wasm_invoke_method @ 00971d3e:0x969f
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_EndInvokeJS @ managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_EndInvokeJS:16
endInvokeJSFromDotNet @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
Promise.then (async)
beginInvokeJSFromDotNet @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
St @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
$func219 @ 00971d3e:0x1a492
$func167 @ 00971d3e:0xce60
$func166 @ 00971d3e:0xbd73
$func2815 @ 00971d3e:0xabec4
$func1619 @ 00971d3e:0x6fc85
$func1623 @ 00971d3e:0x702f2
$mono_wasm_invoke_method @ 00971d3e:0x969f
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_EndInvokeJS @ managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_EndInvokeJS:16
endInvokeJSFromDotNet @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
Promise.then (async)
beginInvokeJSFromDotNet @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
St @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
$func219 @ 00971d3e:0x1a492
$func167 @ 00971d3e:0xce60
$func166 @ 00971d3e:0xbd73
$func2815 @ 00971d3e:0xabec4
$func1619 @ 00971d3e:0x6fc85
$func1623 @ 00971d3e:0x702f2
$mono_wasm_invoke_method @ 00971d3e:0x969f
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_EndInvokeJS @ managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_EndInvokeJS:16
endInvokeJSFromDotNet @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
Promise.then (async)
beginInvokeJSFromDotNet @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
St @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
$func219 @ 00971d3e:0x1a492
$func167 @ 00971d3e:0xce60
$func166 @ 00971d3e:0xbd73
$func2815 @ 00971d3e:0xabec4
$func1619 @ 00971d3e:0x6fc85
$func1623 @ 00971d3e:0x702f2
$mono_wasm_invoke_method @ 00971d3e:0x969f
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_EndInvokeJS @ managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_EndInvokeJS:16
endInvokeJSFromDotNet @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
Promise.then (async)
beginInvokeJSFromDotNet @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
St @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
$func219 @ 00971d3e:0x1a492
$func167 @ 00971d3e:0xce60
$func166 @ 00971d3e:0xbd73
$func2815 @ 00971d3e:0xabec4
$func1619 @ 00971d3e:0x6fc85
$func1623 @ 00971d3e:0x702f2
$mono_wasm_invoke_method @ 00971d3e:0x969f
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
managed_BINDINGS_SetTaskSourceResult @ managed_BINDINGS_SetTaskSourceResult:17
(anonymous) @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
Promise.then (async)
_wrap_js_thenable_as_task @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
_js_to_mono_obj @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
js_to_mono_obj @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
receiveHotReload @ blazor-hotreload.js:2
St @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
$func219 @ 00971d3e:0x1a492
$func167 @ 00971d3e:0xce60
$func166 @ 00971d3e:0xbd73
$func2815 @ 00971d3e:0xabec4
$func1619 @ 00971d3e:0x6fc85
$func1623 @ 00971d3e:0x702f2
$mono_wasm_invoke_method @ 00971d3e:0x969f
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_EndInvokeJS @ managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_EndInvokeJS:16
endInvokeJSFromDotNet @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
Promise.then (async)
beginInvokeJSFromDotNet @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
St @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
$func219 @ 00971d3e:0x1a492
$func167 @ 00971d3e:0xce60
$func166 @ 00971d3e:0xbd73
$func2815 @ 00971d3e:0xabec4
$func1619 @ 00971d3e:0x6fc85
$func1623 @ 00971d3e:0x702f2
$mono_wasm_invoke_method @ 00971d3e:0x969f
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
managed_BINDINGS_SetTaskSourceResult @ managed_BINDINGS_SetTaskSourceResult:17
(anonymous) @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
Promise.then (async)
_wrap_js_thenable_as_task @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
_js_to_mono_obj @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
js_to_mono_obj @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
Fe._internal.getSatelliteAssemblies @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
St @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
$func219 @ 00971d3e:0x1a492
$func167 @ 00971d3e:0xce60
$func166 @ 00971d3e:0xbd73
$func2815 @ 00971d3e:0xabec4
$func1619 @ 00971d3e:0x6fc85
$func1623 @ 00971d3e:0x702f2
$mono_wasm_invoke_method @ 00971d3e:0x969f
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
_call_method_with_converted_args @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
call_method @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
(anonymous) @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
call_assembly_entry_point @ dotnet.6.0.11.yp634snq4a.js:1
callEntryPoint @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
At @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
await in At (async)
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69061817/exclude-error-razor-page-from-openidconnect-authentication

Comment: @FitriHalim that's not true

Comment: You can put the ```@attribute [AllowAnonymous]``` inside ```import.razor``` and remove the ```@attribute [Authorize]```

Comment: i've tried, but i don't why it didn't work

Answer (score 4):

I've added these lines in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Booking.ServerAPI.Anonymous", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
});
```

fetchPeople.razor

```
@page "/fetchpeople"
@using Booking.Shared
@inject IHttpClientFactory _factory
@inject HttpClient Http

<PageTitle>People</PageTitle>

<h1>People</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                    <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                    <th>Summary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@forecast.Id</td>
                            <td>@forecast.FirstName</td>
                            <td>@forecast.LastName</td>
                            <td>@forecast.LastName</td>
                        </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
}

@code {
    private PersonModel[]? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = _factory.CreateClient("Booking.ServerAPI.Anonymous");
        forecasts = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<PersonModel[]>("People");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh nice. I don't we can do like this. Awesome.